# Looping through list of xml-files?

Tags: python, xml, function, for-loop, elementtree

I'm trying to create a program that loops through a list of xml-files and extracts certain elements from the files:

```
from os import listdir, path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mypath = 'C:\myfolder'

files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

for file in files:
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

ns = {namespaces}

def myfunction():
    if 'something' in root.tag:
        filename = path.splitext(file)[0]
        var1 = root.find('./element1', ns)
        var2 = root.find('./element2', ns)

        row = [
            var1.text,
            var2.text
            ]

    return row
```

The above code returns a list with var1, var2 (from the last file) if I call the function. The reason I have defined this function is that there are different types of xml-files with different element names, so I'm going to create a function for each file type.

Now I want to create a table where the output from each file is a row i.e.:

```
filename1, var1, var2
filename2, var1, var2
ect.
```

And ideally export the table to a csv-file. How do I go about that?

Comment: Your question isn't really about looping through xml files, it's about extracting and data from each of those files and writing a new file. I suggest you consider using the [`csv'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to create the new file.

Comment: Did it work? If it did, could you upvote and mark it as correct? Otherwise, please tell me what went wrong.

Comment: It only writes the variables from the last file. Maybe something is wrong with my loop? I have a few thousand files, so there should be a line for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to write a CSV file is using the [Standard CSV](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html).
To write a CSV file, is as simple as opening the file and using the default writer:

```
import csv
from os import listdir, path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mypath = 'C:\myfolder'

files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.xml')]

for file in files:
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

ns = {namespaces}

def myfunction():
    if 'something' in root.tag:
        filename = path.splitext(file)[0]
        var1 = root.find('./element1', ns)
        var2 = root.find('./element2', ns)

        row = [
            var1.text,
            var2.text
            ]

        # Open the file and store the data
        with open('outfile.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

    return row
```

Note that `csf.writer` receives a list as parameter.